# How to refresh richdatatable with datascroller?

Tags: jsf, richdatatable, datascroller

I'm using RichFaces 4.0 and I'm trying to show a rich:dataTable that has been paginated using a dataScroller.

> ```
> <!-- DATA TABLE -->
>
> <rich:dataTable id="myTable"
> cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" var="var"
> value="#{myService.list}" headerClass="headerClass" rows="10"
> styleClass="table">
>
>
> <!-- DATA SCROLLER -->
> <rich:dataScroller for="myTable" pageIndexVar="pageIndex" pagesVar="pages" page="#{myervice.scrollerPage}">
> <f:facet name="pages">
> <h:outputText value="#{pageIndex} / #{pages}" />
> </f:facet>
> </rich:dataScroller>
> ```

The table is paginated ok but something strange happens with the links:

When I click a link (for example the link of the page 2) nothing happens, but when just after I refresh the page (with the F5 key) then refresh the page and the table shows the page 2 successfully.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tested here with a simple @RequestScoped backing bean (JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4.0), initializing the list in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method, and everything worked. How is your backing bean, and how are you initializing your list?

Comment: Make sure your managed bean has @ViewScoped, also your `<rich:dataScroller>` must be in the footer section of your dataTable.